# how to highlight text form input search with Javascript

Tags: javascript, search, highlight

I have a todoList with keyword search, how can I make sure that when I enter a keyword, the content below will be highlighted?

```
function keysSearch() {
    const inputSearchValue = inputSearch.value.trim().toUpperCase();
    const loadData = loadLocalStorageData();
    const filterSearch = loadData.filter(function (value) {
        if (inputSearchValue) {
            return value.task.toUpperCase().indexOf(inputSearchValue) !== -1
        } else {
            return loadData
        }
    });
    render(filterSearch);
}
```

[image]

Comment: One of the ways: Simply use `<mark>te</mark>st` to do the job

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the innerHTML property to add HTML tags around the matched text. You can also use the replace method to replace the matched text with the same text wrapped in a  tag with a specific class.

```
function keysSearch() {
    const inputSearchValue = inputSearch.value.trim().toUpperCase();
    const loadData = loadLocalStorageData();
    const contentDiv = document.getElementById("content");
    const filterSearch = loadData.filter(function (value) {
      if (inputSearchValue) {

        value.task = value.task.replace(new RegExp(inputSearchValue, "gi"), (match) => `<span class="highlight">${match}</span>`)
        return value.task.toUpperCase().indexOf(inputSearchValue) !== -1
      } else {
        return loadData
      }
    });

    contentDiv.innerHTML = render(filterSearch);
}
```

You will also need to add a CSS class for the highlighted text

```
.highlight{
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

Comment: oh wow,  it worked, I thought about it but didn't know how to write it , thanks u so much.